# Contentful server side rendering dynamic routes in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, contentful

According to Next.js, to render a dynamic path you need both `getStaticPaths()` and `getStaticProps()` the problem with this for me is, the data of the page is being cached. I'm using Contentful for my page data, but when I make an update in my post the update doesn't make it to the page. I have to re-compile and push to my production in order for the change to take place.

However, for non-dynamic routes I can use `getServerSideProps()` and it works no problem.

I know with SWR you can render client-side, but with updated data.

Is there a way to render the Contentful data in a dynamic route during run-time with SWR rather than using Contentful's `client.getEntry` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` for dynamic routes if you want them statically generated at build-time (SSG). You can use `getServerSideProps` instead on your dynamic routes if you want the data fetched at runtime - there is no issue with that, especially since you are already doing that for other pages.

See [this section of the documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) that mentions using dynamic routes with `getServerSideProps`.

Comment: Right, but i'm using [slug].js to dynamically render the page. With `getServerSideProps` i'd have to build a page for each post right (post1.js, post2.js etc..) ?

Comment: No, `getServerSideProps` will have the `params` parameter which will contain `post1`, `post2`, etc.